# TextBox Visible attribute

Tags: c#

I am currently working with visible attributes on textboxes. Below I copy pasted a snippet of my code. I have several textboxes in my form. It is going to become very tedious trying to write it as I have below for all the textboxes. Is there a way to compress my code to a few lines to make the textboxes visible?

```
    public void makeVisible()
    {
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        //etc.

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach(Control c in Controls)
{
 TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
 if (tb !=null) tb.Visible = false; //or true, whatever.
}
```

For limited textboxes:

```
int count = 0;  
int txtBoxVisible = 4;  
foreach(Control c in Controls)
{
    if(count <= txtBoxVisible)
    {
        TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
        if (tb !=null) tb.Visible = false; //or true, whatever.
        count++;
    }
}
```

You can set `txtBoxVisible` according to your need.

Comment: +1 Thank you, but Lets say i have 8 textboxes in total but I only want to make the first 4 visible?

Comment: As I mentioned above take some condition as if textbox value is null do something(hide/show)

Comment: @Shayharyar-Thanks for extending it.

Comment: Perfect! now i understand.

Answer (score 1):

Put the textboxes in an array and loop through the array or

put the textboxes in a panel, grid, group, ... and change the visibility of that container.

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to the following:

```
foreach (TextBox textBox in container.Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<TextBox>())
{
    textBox.Visible = value;
}
```

---

Refer to the following:

[LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)

[Enumerable.Cast Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)

[Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

Comment: +1 Thank you, but Lets say i have 8 textboxes in total but I only want to make the first 4 visible?

Comment: Append Take(4) to the linq statement.

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner, so i am not sure how would I incorporate that to your example?

Comment: container.Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<TextBox>().Take(4)